# How to store data from PromiseResult? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I'm trying to **store** data from PromiseResult for a long while. I have a function API and it returns a promise value.

I tried to store the data like this:

```
const questionList = []
const getAllQuestion = async () => {
   questionList = await readAllQuestion()
   console.log(questionList)   // 1
}
console.log(questionList)   // 2
```

But the things is the value of `questionList` is different in 1 and 2. The console from 1 is correct and has all the data, but from 2 is nothing which is empty as it was declared.

How do I solve this and how can I store data in this situation? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: This is called as state management. There are multiple libraries out there that can help you with this but react has a built-in mechanism for handling state: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html Avoid using globals because it will lead to difficult-to-debug errors in future.

Comment: You maintain your questionList variable as a const.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you have used

```
const questionList = []
```

Constants (const) cannot be changed. So inside the **getAllQuestion** function value of **questionList** cannot be changed.

Second, you haven't called the **getAllQuestion** function anywhere in your code. You need to call the call the function in order to execute.

The modified code is given below:

```
let questionList = [];
const getAllQuestion = async () => {
   questionList = await readAllQuestion()
   console.log(questionList)   // 1
}
getAllQuestion();
console.log(questionList)   // 2
```

Comment: I tried and change to `let`, but still it's not working. The console from 2 is empty...thanks though